# Robotframework: how to create json that include list

Tags: json, robotframework

I use robot framework at following environment.

- Python 2.7.6
- robotframework 2.8.7
- Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

I want to create json that include list.
But Following script,Json.dumps interpret part as string.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections
Library    json
Library    String

*** Variables ***
${NAME}    XXXX
${ID}    YYYY
${PART_1}    ZZZ1
${PART_2}    ZZZ2

*** Test Cases ***
Test Create Json
    ${req_dict}    Create Dictionary    name=${NAME}    id=${ID}    part=[${PART_1},${PART_2}]
    Log To Console    *** Test Create Json Result ***
    Log To Console    ${req_json}

*** Keywords ***
Prepare Json Keyword
    [Arguments]    @{args}
    ${req_dict}    Create Dictionary
    :FOR     ${pair}    IN     @{args}
    \     ${key}    ${value}=     Split String    ${pair}    =
    \     Set To Dictionary    ${req_dict}    ${key}=${value}
    ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${req_dict}
    [Return]    ${req_json}
```

This case,Robot shows

```
{"part": "[ZZZ1,ZZZ2]", "name": "XXXX", "id": "YYYY"}
```

But I want to create json like following.

```
{"part": ["ZZZ1","ZZZ2"], "name": "XXXX", "id": "YYYY"}
```

To interpret list, how can I change it ?

Comment: is there a reason you're creating the json from a dictionary, rather than just hard-coding the actual json string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you want to achieve this?:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    json

*** Variables ***
${NAME}    XXXX
${ID}    YYYY
${PART_1}    ZZZ1
${PART_2}    ZZZ2
@{parts}    ${PART_1}    ${PART_2}

*** Test Cases ***
Test Create Json
    ${req_dict}    Create Dictionary    name=${NAME}    id=${ID}    part=@{parts}
    Log To Console    \n*** DICTIONARY ***
    Log To Console    ${req_dict}
    ${req_json}    Json.Dumps    ${req_dict}
    Log To Console    *** JSON ***
    Log To Console    ${req_json}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your sample and it works correctly! But additional problem occurs... in my case some arguments want to be evaluated integer not string.If I grant this, should I cast in dictionary? Or is there some better way?

Comment: `*** Settings ***
Library   Collections
Library   json
Library   String

*** Variables ***
@{parts}   Z1   Z2
${INT}   123

*** Test Cases ***
Test1
    ${req}   MyKw   part=@{parts}   type=${INT}
    Log To Console   ${req}

*** Keywords ***
MyKw
    [Arguments]   @{args}
    ${req_dict}   Create Dictionary
    :FOR    ${pair}   IN    @{args}
    \    ${key}   ${value}=    Split String   ${pair}   =
    \    Set To Dictionary   ${req_dict}   ${key}=${value}
    ${tmp_json}   Json.Dumps   ${req_dict}
    ${req_json}   Replace String   ${tmp_json}   u'   '
    [Return]   ${req_json}
`

Comment: I'm sorry it's too hard to see. I want to create following json. `{"part": "['Z1', 'Z2']", "type": 123}`

Comment: Numbers in Robot are written in ${number} markup. Example: ${88}.
If you find my answer correct, mark it then properly :)